# Strange Mono CookieContainer Behavior

Tags: c#, .net, mono

Here's the code:

Essentially Logon.Cookies is just a cookie container built from a response from a logon page. Its value should never change after logging on.

On Windows .NET 4.5, the cookie count stays at 8.

On mono on ubuntu, the cookie count increments by 2 for each loop of this function call - and I believe it's what's responsible for the issues staying logged in.

Multiple hosts are being used, so perhaps that's why - but again, Logon.Cookies should never change after logging on.

```
Uri newUri = new Uri(FinalURL.Replace(HostMain, Hosts[bestHostIndex]));
                var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(newUri);
                request.Method = "GET";
                request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 1000;
                request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                request.KeepAlive = true;
                request.Referer = EscapedURL;
                request.UserAgent = UA;
                request.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
                request.Timeout = 3000;
                request.ReadWriteTimeout = 3000;
                request.Host = HostMain;
                request.Proxy = null;
                request.CookieContainer = Logon.Cookies;
                Console.WriteLine("Container count: {0}\r\nCookies count: {1}", request.CookieContainer.Count, Logon.Cookies.Count);
                using (var resp = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (var responseStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            ret = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }

                }

                return ret;
```

Example output from mono (ignore the # 0 0):

```
3        0       0
Container count: 11
Cookies count: 11
4        0       0
Container count: 13
Cookies count: 13
5        0       0
Container count: 15
Cookies count: 15
6        0       0
Container count: 17
Cookies count: 17
7        0       0
Container count: 19
Cookies count: 19
8        0       0
Container count: 21
Cookies count: 21
c9       0       0
Container count: 23
Cookies count: 23
10       0       0
Container count: 25
Cookies count: 25
11       0       0
Container count: 27
Cookies count: 27
12       0       0
Container count: 29
Cookies count: 29
13       0       0
Container count: 31
Cookies count: 31
c14      0       0
Container count: 33
Cookies count: 33
15       0       0
Container count: 35
Cookies count: 35
```

Edit:

Ok the issue is that after the response from the webserver, mono continues to add the cookies the cookies to the container. seems to be a mono bug

Comment: what version of mono are you using?

Comment: "Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.8" -- which seems to be outdated, but I'm assuming that using apt-get install mono would yield the latest version of mono.

I believe the issue is that I'm switching URLs, and mono is assigning a new cookie to the container despite the host being the same. Perhaps this is fixed in later mono builds. Will try to update it.